# take one value out of fetchone sqlalchemy query result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

from a lambda function in AWS I am calling a stored procedure in Snowflake. I run python code and use sqlalchemy and snowflake.sqlalchemy modules to call the snowflake stored proc. the stored procedure queries a table with one row and one column, does a simple calculation and returns a single value. The code looks like this:

```
result=connection.execute('CALL TEST_GET_PARAMS(8,8);')
sql='select * from CALCRESULT;'
rows = result.fetchone()
print(rows)
print (type(rows))
```

the return looks like this:

```
(160.0,)
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy'>
```

However, I want to value to be an int value without the ( ) and ,

I am assuming my problem is in the use of fetchone and then how take the first column out of the result, but I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The [`RowProxy` object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) returned by `result.fetchone()` permits [dictionary-style access](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#basic-usage) of columns within.

For example, if the lone column inside your `CALCRESULT` table is called `COLUMN_NAME` then you can use this to retrieve just its value:

```py
>>> […]
>>> row = result.fetchone()

>>> value = row["COLUMN_NAME"]
>>> print(value)
160.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fetchmany(size=1) inplace of fetchone().And define the size limit according to your column requirement.